# colorize df output if Use% => 80%

Tags: perl, awk, sed, grep, cat

I have 40+ remote sites that I run a daily CRONTAB that collects df -h from each sites servers and appends it to a daily log file on our report server at the home office.
Is there an easy way to cat / grep / sed / awk / perl / this file so that any lines that have a Use% of 80%, or more, gets highlighted/colorized, so there is less chance of a server with storage limitations being overlooked?

Thank you, for your assistance.

Comment: It would be harder to overlook if you only logged actual problems. Even with color coding, you could easily miss one if you're sifting through hundreds of lines of df output.

Answer (score 6):

Try

```
grep --color=auto '[8-9][0-9]%\|100%\|$' logfile
```

- `--color=auto` to highlight matched text
- `[8-9][0-9]%` match text in the range 80-99%
- `\|100%` or 100% (not sure if it is a valid value)
- `\|$` or end of line - a trick to output all other lines without highlighting anything

To highlight entire matching line

```
grep --color=auto '.*\([8-9][0-9]%\|100%\).*\|$' logfile
```

or with ERE

```
grep -E --color=auto '.*([8-9][0-9]%|100%).*|$' logfile
```